# What permission does it require for moving files within a WordPress file hierarchy?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, bulk

On a WordPress instance, I'm trying to move a large number of media files to a different folder using `sudo find folder2 -name '*.*' | xargs mv --target-directory=folder`, but I get a permission denied even after changing the folder permission to `777`.